# Flag Value Based on Year Month and Value from Another Column

Tags: sql

I have a data spec which contains Id (Member's ID), Diag_cd (Diagnosis Code), Category_Nm, Year_Mo (Year and Month) and CancerFlag. What I want to do is to add a new column which will determine 0 for the first month of diagnosis which is CancerFlag = 1.  The month before diagnosis will be -1, the two months before diagnosis will be -2 and so forth.....the month after the diagnosis will be 1, the two months after diagnosis will be 2 and so forth....
Here's my code so far:

```
    SELECT a.Id, Diag_cd, Category Name, Year_mo
      , CancerFlag = CASE WHEN Categroy_Name like '%cancer of breast%'
      and Diag_desc <> 'UNKOWN DIAGNOSIS'
      and Year_NBR = 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM #member AS a
    INNER JOIN Mini..Fact as fc on a.Id = f.Id
    INNER JOIN Mini..Diagnosis as d on fc.Diag_cd = d.Diag_cd
    INNER JOIN Mini..Date as d dt on fc.Dt_Id = dt.Dt_Id
```

My desired output should be like this:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZZnA.png)

The **bold** column is what I can't get. Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: I already added sample table and expected result in the desired output, please check the image.

Answer (score 0):

Some things are not clear:

1. What field contains the information about when the diagnosis took place?
2. What is Year_mo?
3. When you are talking about "first month of diagnosis" etc, what is your point of reference, e.g. if I call the sql today and the diagnosis was 5 weeks ago, does that mean it is +1, or is the comparison between the diganosis date and  another point in time?
4. How are you calculating month - are you meaning how many calendar months between the 2 dates or how many chunks of 4.2 weeks? i.e. if the date is 10th May 2017 and the point of reference is 25th April 2017, would that be +1 (i.e. April to May) or 0 because there is less than a month between them?

Comment: 1. Fore reference when the diagnosis took place, the columns Year_mo has it.
2. Year_mo is the columns that has the year and month when the diagnosis which is the diag_cd
3. The point of reference should be the year_mo when the member was diagnosed with cancer or has CancerFlag = 1,  for those months that are before the months where member was diagnosed with cancer should be -1 and so on, while for the next months after month of diagnosis it should be 1 and so on.
4. That should be 1 already since I am basin it only per month not per day.

Comment: 1. Fore reference when the diagnosis took place, the columns Year_mo has it.  
2. Year_mo is the columns that has the year and month when the diagnosis which is the diag_cd  
3. The point of reference should be the year_mo when the member was diagnosed with cancer or has CancerFlag = 1,  for those months that are before the months where member was diagnosed with cancer should be -1 and so on, while for the next months after month of diagnosis it should be 1 and so on.  
4. That should be 1 already since I am basin it only per month not per day.

Comment: Sorry about my formatting for comments. I'm new to stackoverflow and still learning proper formatting. Can't edit those comment unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, mostly clear now - still need the point of reference against which the year_mo should be calculated for your desired column. +1, -3 etc is a comparison between year_mo and what other date?